# Order class objects are displayed on the screen

Tags: pygame

I am very new to Python and Pygame, if anyone can help point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it :)

From what I understand, the order these are displayed determines how they will appear.
I need the "ticker" to appear in front of the other class object, "tickerchart" but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

self.ticker_movement() is first on the list.

Can anyone tell me why the ticker is not showing up on top of the "tickerchart" image when it moves to the same space on the screen?

```
class Ticker:
    def __init__(self, main_ticker_screen):
        self.main_ticker_screen = main_ticker_screen
        TICKER_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Desktop\Coding\PYTHON\EXPERIMENT\assets\ticker.png').convert_alpha()
        self.TICKER = pygame.transform.scale(TICKER_IMAGE, (6, 95))
        self.TICKER_x = 1277.5
        self.TICKER_y = 841
        self.TICKER_direction = 'none'

    def move_right(self):
        self.TICKER_direction = 'right'

    def move_left(self):
        self.TICKER_direction = 'left'

    def stopmoving(self):
        self.TICKER_direction = 'none'

    def drawticker(self):
        self.main_ticker_screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.main_ticker_screen.blit(self.TICKER, (self.TICKER_x, self.TICKER_y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    def movement(self):
        if self.TICKER_direction == 'right':
            self.TICKER_x += 22
        if self.TICKER_direction == 'left':
            self.TICKER_x -= 22
        if self.TICKER_direction == 'none':
            self.TICKER_x = self.TICKER_x
            
        self.drawticker()



class TickerChart:
    def __init__(self, ticker_screen):
        self.ticker_screen = ticker_screen

        FORTY_ONE_LEFT_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Desktop\Coding\PYTHON\EXPERIMENT\assets\41.png').convert_alpha()
        self.FORTY_ONE = pygame.transform.scale(FORTY_ONE_IMAGE, (6, 120))

    def draw_tickerchart(self):
        #greytickers #left - 40s
        self.ticker_screen.blit(self.FORTY_ONE, (1079.5, 816))
       
        pygame.display.flip()
        


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((2555, 1005))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PBF SCORE")
        self.surface.fill(BLACK)
        SCOREBOARD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Desktop\Coding\PYTHON\EXPERIMENT\assets\score_board.png').convert_alpha()
        self.SCOREBOARD = pygame.transform.scale(SCOREBOARD_IMAGE, (1236, 700))
        self.surface.blit(self.SCOREBOARD, (650, 0))
        self.ticker = Ticker(self.surface)
        self.ticker.drawticker()
        self.tickerchart = TickerChart(self.surface)
        self.tickerchart.draw_tickerchart()


    def run(self):

        running = True
        
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False

                    if event.key == K_q:
                        self.ticker.move_right()

                    if event.key == K_o:
                        self.ticker.move_left()

                    if event.key == K_p:
                        self.ticker.stopmoving()

                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False

            
            self.ticker.movement()
            self.surface.blit(self.SCOREBOARD, (650, 0))
            self.tickerchart.draw_tickerchart()
            

            time.sleep(0.65)
   
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Comment: Please post only the part of the code that is relevant to your problem in order to make it more readable and understandable to others. I couldn't reproduce your problem, but just looking at your code I saw at least one problem with `pygame.display.flip()`, you should only call this once, at the end of each iteration of you main loop, but your are calling it multiple times and that can cause weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A *possible* problem might be that you arent calling for Ticket to be drawn every frame, only them the Game() class is initialized.

Put this in the run loop:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((2555, 1005))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PBF SCORE")
        self.surface.fill(BLACK)
        SCOREBOARD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Desktop\Coding\PYTHON\EXPERIMENT\assets\score_board.png').convert_alpha()
        self.SCOREBOARD = pygame.transform.scale(SCOREBOARD_IMAGE, (1236, 700))
        self.surface.blit(self.SCOREBOARD, (650, 0))
        self.ticker = Ticker(self.surface)
        self.ticker.drawticker()
        self.tickerchart = TickerChart(self.surface)
        self.tickerchart.draw_tickerchart()

    def run(self):

        running = True

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False

                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        self.ticker.move_right()

                    if event.key == pygame.K_o:
                        self.ticker.move_left()

                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        self.ticker.stopmoving()

                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

            self.ticker.movement()
            self.surface.blit(self.SCOREBOARD, (650, 0))
            self.tickerchart.draw_tickerchart()  # just add this line!!

            time.sleep(0.65)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

I ran this and it seemed to work fine, the ticker (the moving object i presume) does apear and it does move around.

You just need to change ONE line of code in the Game class.